# Update first object attribute in stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
    public List<Data> toData(List<Signatory> signatories) {
    List<Data> data= signatories.stream().sorted().map(input -> {
        if (input == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot be null");
        }
        if (isStrictSigningOrderEnabled()) {
            return getData(input,false);
        }
        return getData(input,true);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    data.stream().filter(input -> !input.getStatus().equals(SignatoryStatus.COMPLETE))
            .findFirst().ifPresent(obj -> obj.setCanSign(true));
```

I want to avoid using the second stream and have the job implemented in it done as part of the first stream. Since the first stream handles `Signatory` data and the second handles `Data` data, I need to clarify that if I was to integrate the functionality of the second stream into the first one what I would want to happen is, that for the first `Signatory` object where `!input.getStatus().equals(SignatoryStatus.COMPLETE)` is true (`Signatory` and `Data` both have this method), I want to call the `from(input, true)` method. Is that possible?

I was thinking maybe an atomic counter? If it is not possible, to do what I want, it would also be helpful if someone pointed it out.

Comment: What is `from` method?

Comment: Just method that returns boolean